# Hierarchical State Machine in IEC 61131-3

Tags: automata, state-machine, iec61131-3

I would like implement a HSM in 61131-3. Doing some reading I understand that HSM's are a sort of subset of pushdown automata?

Most of the examples from other languages are using pointers and references, which I would like to avoid. Is it feasible to implement a HSM without using pointers or references?

I guess I need an event stack and a stack for the nesting of the stack?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's supported by your programing software SFC (sequential function chart) might be what your looking for.  SFC is a graphical programing language based on actions and transitions.  It avoids pointers and is one of the five IEC 61131-3 languages.